# Consuming WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I tried to consume a wcf data service reference I made earlier. everything was in order until I tried to load the data in a datagrid in the client, but it only load the column header. no data being loaded, although the database are filled with data.

there are no error was being thrown by visual studio.

Here are the codes and the screenshot on what's going on

```
namespace AccountingApplication.Views.Invoices
{
    public partial class InvoicePages : Page
    {
        InventoryEntities SalesOrderHeaderContext = new InventoryEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:9090/EntityDataServices/EntityDataServices.svc/"));
        DataServiceCollection<SalesOrderHeader> SalesOrderCollection = new DataServiceCollection<SalesOrderHeader>();

        public InvoicePages()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadSalesOrderHeader();
        }

        private void LoadSalesOrderHeader()
        {
            SalesOrderCollection.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(SalesOrderCollection_loadCompleted);
            var soQuery = from salesOrder in SalesOrderHeaderContext.SalesOrderHeaders 
                          select salesOrder;
            SalesOrderCollection.LoadAsync(soQuery );
        }

        private void SalesOrderCollection_loadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            SalesOrderHeaderRadGridView.ItemsSource = SalesOrderCollection.ToList();
            testDG.ItemsSource = SalesOrderCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok apparently almost all tutorial on the internet use these lines as clientaccesspolicy.xml put in like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

this line cause a major issue on this line since silverlight 4

```
<allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
```

we have to change the http-request-headers="*"> in order to make the web service works.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, but it seams you pick data from db in this line

```
var SOQuery = from salesOrder in SalesOrderHeaderContext.SalesOrderHeaders select salesOrder;
```

yet you do not put SOQuery anywhere. I just don't see what you do with selected data. You collected data, but you are not using it. SOQuery should be some kind of list now. Hope this helps any.

Comment: Yes, You're correct, but even when I use   SalesOrderCollection.LoadAsync(SOQuery); like this. it still does not show the records. Only the column header like in the screen shot

Comment: Ok. Then,this event handler you have before selecting data, what does it do for you? Are you trying to fill data on the page, before doing the selection from the db?

Comment: Honestly speaking I only follow the tutorial... I have no idea what i'm doing :D

Comment: :D that's ok , too. So,to explain it in a more simple way: += new EventHandler will call SalesOrderCollection_loadCompleted which will put collection in the source of data grid. But your selection from db happens afterwards.

Comment: Try putting this line SalesOrderCollection.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(SalesOrderCollection_loadCompleted); after this line SalesOrderCollection.LoadAsync(SOQuery); It makes more sene to first make a collection of data,and only then display it. I don't have any project to test this on,so it's trial and error. :)

Comment: try putting break points on those lines,and then trace what happens to collection and query. Are they filled with data like the database.

Comment: I did... Unfortunately no... but got no error message tho... i don't get it.. nothing is broken

Comment: trace back what you can, and check if you miss something for it to work. is the tutorial you are following the same as this code?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer, but I will need to get some sleep first. I'll post the answer first thing in the morning